# count columns where column1 LIKE %something%

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dataset which is not set out the best way see a sample of it below.

```
col1|col2|col3
john smith|10|3
tom smith|8|3
sean smith|12|3
sean smith|5|33
john smith|3|32
john smith|6|13
```

As you can see col1 has multiple records that are the same.

I want to be able to group all the entries with the same value in col1 and output then into the one row I also want to display another column which is the sum of col2*col3 so that my output would look like the below.

```
col1|col2|col3
john smith|19|48|912
sean smith|17|36|612
tom smith|8|3|24
```

Would it be best to use mySQL Sum here?  How can I write this select statement when I don't know what 'WHERE' will be but I just want it to output the result for each name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this too ::

```
Select 
col1, SUM(col2), SUM(col3), SUM(col3)*SUM(col2) 
from table group by col1
```

Comment: thanks, this works well if I want to order by the sum col3*col2 is there a better way to do this than ORDER BY SUM( col3 ) * SUM( col2 ) ASC (this works it just might become long in some cases though if the sum is more complex)

Comment: @ak85: I just gave you the same query what Sashi kant has answered(with a little modification), but try his query, since he has refered the columns as alias

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select 
col1, SUM(col2) as b, SUM(col3) as c, SUM(col2)*SUM(col3) as d
from table group by col1
```

Comment: I get an error here **Unknown column 'b' in 'field list'** with the above code.  When I take out , b*c it has no errors but oviously doesn't output the sum of b*c. I have reviewed some documentation about sql alias and can't see anything wrong with this. Do you know what the problem might be here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1,SUM(col2),SUM(col3),SUM(col2)*SUM(col3) FROM table
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: Then what is the diff between your and Shanky's answer, Please post something which is different, If the answer what you are thinking then please appreciate it with an upvote

Comment: Lol, added it before your comment! Got stressed, figured a lot would answer quickly on such an easy question ;)